# serverless aws python lambda unable to import module from parent directory

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have following structure

[image]

I am trying to import utils inside handler.py

I tried giving like

```
from src.utils import *
from utils import *
```

also tried adding

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

and

```
import os
    import sys
    
    sys.path.append('src')
```

but nothing working

I am using serverless framework not manually uploading the zip file

Tried alot but nothing working...

Any help,
highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is confusing because based on what you have provided this seems correct, do you have a typo somewhere? Or where are you seeing the import error is it when you are deployed to an environment or are you seeing from the IDE that you can't access anything from utils?

Comment: get rid of the src directory and move your python scripts up to the root level. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can install `serverless-functions-base-path` plugin and use.

Check out the guide on the plugin here https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-functions-base-path

If your serverless.yml file and src in the directory, you can add this to you serverless.yml file and try deploy

```
custom:
  functionsBasePath: src

plugins:
  - serverless-functions-base-path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use serverless-python-requirements plugin for this.

It can be installed locally or on a pipeline with

```
sls plugin install -n serverless-python-requirements
```

You can add this to you serverless.yml file and try deploy

```
# this part might not be needed depending on size of utils
custom:
  pythonRequirements:
    zip: true

# This plugin allows us import dependencies
plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

Check out the guide on the plugin here

https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging

https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-python-requirements